# Tradução de texto quando máximo numero de análises diária é atingida

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Quando cheguei ao máximo de 20 análises por dia, apareceu este texto meio traduzido.

> Thank you for reviewing 20 Edições sugeridas today; come back em 1 hora to continue reviewing.

Sugestão de tradução:

> Obrigado por ter analisado 20 Edições sugeridas hoje; volte daqui a 1 hora para poder continuar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas expressões já foram *internacionalizadas*, mas ainda não foram traduzidas, pelo que o sistema usa a versão em Inglês. Nós normalmente temos uma "entrega" de expressões traduzidas a cada duas semanas, de modo que o problema vai desaparecer em breve.

---

> Those sentences have now been localized, but have not been translated yet so the system uses the English version. We usually have a "drop" of translated strings every couple of weeks, so the problem will go away shortly.

Comment: Thanks for keeping us updated! Keep on the good job!